# C# Statement Tokens

Tags: c#

Somewhere I've read:

> Statements are formed from tokens. These tokens can be keywords, identifiers (variables), operators, and the statement terminator which is the semicolon (;).

I was wondering, are these the only "tokens" from which C# statements are formed? Are there any other that are not mentioned?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx

Comment: yes. proton electron and neutrons. xD

Comment: Literals seem to be missing, and I wonder if `()` is an operator. This quote seems to be informal, just take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

It is the way a compiler writer would talk about statements. the tokens are generated by the lexer (aka lexical analyzer), the parser interprets them to parse valid statements. Not specific to the C# language, just about any language works that way.  Literals are missing from your list, comments and end-of-file can be tokens.

Specific to the C# compiler, its source is readily available today, there is no keyword token but each keyword is a token by itself.  Like TID_FOR for the "for" keyword and TID_BYTE for the "byte" keyword, etcetera. There are four kinds of literal tokens: number, string, string with @ and character.  Four kind of comments: single line, multiline, /// single and /// multiline.

The C# lexer does not classify operators, just the characters that build them up.  Necessary because, say, '[' and ']' can mean different things (indexing operator vs attribute declaration).  The parser figures out which interpretation is the correct one based on the parser state.

C# has *contextual* keywords, like "yield".  Classified as a regular identifier by the lexer, the parser recognizes it when it sees it followed by "return".  Contextual keywords are good because they avoid breaking a program that accidentally uses "yield" as a variable name.  It was the way they could add "async" and "await" to version 5 without breaking existing programs.